# How to get value of first column in current row in html table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have the following Delete confirmation code using jquery.  The issue is that it assume the location of the name column.  I now have name in the first row.  Instead of using `.prev('td')`, is there anyway to get the value from the first column in the current row using jQuery?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.delete").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("href");

            var name = $(this).parent().prev('td').prev('td').text();

            jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this:' + name, 'Application Delete', function(r) {
                if (r) {
                    window.location = url;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You may take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796559/jquery-get-first-column-value-on-fourth-row-only-of-html-table

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use under each

```
var name = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:first').text();
```

this goes to the row and then to the first cell of the row. That's more intuitive.

**Edit**: I changed `'tr'` to `'tr:first'`, but in real this should often not be needed, because nested tables more than often indicate a different problem in the whole design (tables for layout?) which needs to be fixed differently.

Comment: hmm .. this seems to give me a string that represents the whole table heading . .any ideas what could be wrong ?

Comment: Apparently you're nesting tables (why by the way?). Replace `tr` by `tr:first`.

Comment: yes, this is a nested table . . basically for layout purposes as their is a main table that represents the whole page and this is a section within the main page . .