# jQuery: Get First Column Value on Fourth Row (only) of HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table named resultGridTable. I have a jQuery function to be executed on each row of the table.   In the function, "this" means a row.

1. For the fourth row, I need to alert the first column value (of fourth row). I have the following code; but it does not work. How can we make it working?
2. For the fifth row, I need to alert the number of columns in the row. How can we do it?
3. In the sixth row's second column, I have two buttons (input type="submit"). I need to alert the second button's text/value. (The second button has a class named "secondButton") How can we do it?

Following is the code::

```
$('#resultGridTable tr').each(function (i) 
{
    //"this" means row
    //Other operations in the row. Common for all rows

    if(i==3)
    {
        //Specific Operation for fourth row
        var columnValue = $(this 'td:nth-child(0)').val();
        alert(columnValue);
    }
});
```

READINGS:

1. [jQuery Code: Starting from Parent to Child; not from Child to Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798332/jquery-code-starting-from-parent-to-child-not-from-child-to-parent/10798404#10798404)
2. [How to get value of first column in current row in html table using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815859/how-to-get-value-of-first-column-in-current-row-in-html-table-using-jquery)
3. [How to get the first row's last column of an Html table using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871709/how-to-get-the-first-rows-last-column-of-an-html-table-using-jquery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to be different, you can mix up DOM and jQuery to good effect here since you have fixed offsets into the table:

```
var t = document.getElementById('resultGridTable');

// jQuery to get the content of row 4, column 1
var val1 = $(t.rows[3].cells[0]).text();  

// no jQuery here to get that row length!
var val2 = t.rows[4].cells.length;       

// DOM access for the cell, and jQuery to find by class and get the text 
var val3 = $('.secondButton', t.rows[5].cells[1]).text();
```

These *should* all be substantially faster than using selectors.

Comment: This is supported in Microsoft Edge, unlike the other syntax works in Internet Explorer only

Answer (score 7):

Look into [jQuery eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
alert($('#resultGridTable tr:eq(3) > td:eq(0)').text());
alert($('#resultGridTable tr:eq(4) > td').length);
alert($('#resultGridTable tr:eq(5) > td:eq(1) > .secondButton').text());
```

Comment: alert($('#resultGridTable tr:eq(3) > td:eq(0)').text());
that's right man .... but u sure from the second one ??!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have special values for rows/columns, consider adding a class to it, then you can use selectors rather than "magic" numbers which could change.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from Accepted Answer.
This is the code if you are using jquery instead of `document.getElementById` The difference is that you need to insert the array of [0].

```
 var t = $('resultGridTable');

// jQuery to get the content of row 4, column 1
var val1 = $(t[0].rows[3].cells[0]).text();
```