# jQuery Code: Starting from Parent to Child; not from Child to Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML table. In the last column of each row there are three buttons. When view button is clicked, I need to get the consumer ID of the corresponding row. I have the following jQuery code. http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/nUbB2/

1)  Is there a better jQuery code?

2)  Currently I am first finding the button – then its parent row – then the Consumer ID column. Is there a way to start from the row and then find the button and Consumer ID column respectively?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>

 </title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.resultGridTable tr > td > .actionButtonView').click(function () {
            //TRaversing to get the parent row and then the required columns in the row
            var consumerID = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:first').text();
            var consumerName = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
            var configID = $(this).parents('tr:first').find('td:nth-child(5)').text();

            alert(consumerID + "," + consumerName + "," + configID);

            //window.location.href("SubscribedAssociates.aspx?ConsumerID=" + consumerID + "&consumerName=" + consumerName + "&configID=" + configID);
            return false;

        });

    });
</script>
</head>


<body>
<table class="resultGridTable" cellspacing="0" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdConsumers"
    style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                <a>Consumer ID</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a>Consumer Name</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a>Consumer URL</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a>Status</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <a>Config ID</a>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="SubscribedAssociates.aspx?ConsumerID=101">101</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                Consumer1
            </td>
            <td>
                http://Consumer1.compnay.com/wps/payroll
            </td>
            <td>
                Active
            </td>
            <td>
                101
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdConsumers$ctl02$btnView"
                    value="VIEW" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdConsumers_btnView_0" class="actionButtonView"
                    style="color: White; background-color: Orange; font-weight: bold; width: 35px" />
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdConsumers$ctl02$btnEdit"
                    value="EDIT" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdConsumers_btnEdit_0" class="actionButtonEdit"
                    style="color: White; background-color: Orange; font-weight: bold; width: 35px" />
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdConsumers$ctl02$btnDelete"
                    value="DELETE" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdConsumers_btnDelete_0" class="actionButtonDelete"
                    style="color: White; background-color: Orange; font-weight: bold; width: 45px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #E5E5E5;">
            <td>
                <a href="SubscribedAssociates.aspx?ConsumerID=102">102</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                Consumer2
            </td>
            <td>
                http://Consumer2.compnay.com/prd/sap/operations
            </td>
            <td>
                Active
            </td>
            <td>
                102
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdConsumers$ctl03$btnView"
                    value="VIEW" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdConsumers_btnView_1" class="actionButtonView"
                    style="color: White; background-color: Orange; font-weight: bold; width: 35px" />
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdConsumers$ctl03$btnEdit"
                    value="EDIT" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdConsumers_btnEdit_1" class="actionButtonEdit"
                    style="color: White; background-color: Orange; font-weight: bold; width: 35px" />
                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$grdConsumers$ctl03$btnDelete"
                    value="DELETE" id="detailContentPlaceholder_grdConsumers_btnDelete_1" class="actionButtonDelete"
                    style="color: White; background-color: Orange; font-weight: bold; width: 45px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you change the button HTML ? use the `data` attribute and store the customer number in the button - a lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do some traversal, but you can reduce it by caching the row...

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr')[0],
    consumerID = $(row.cells[0]).text(),
    consumerName = $(row.cells[1]).text(),
    configID = $(row.cells[4]).text();
```

I also used the DOM element directly to get the child row.

Answer (score 1):

Change the HTML to store the customer id as a data attribute within the button for example :

```
<input type="button" value="Add" class="actionButtonView " data-customer="101"/>
```

then the jQuery would simply be

```
var customerid = ('.actionButtonView').data('customer');
```

[Docs on .data() here](http://api.jquery.com/data/)